# select data with latest Timestamp from several tables with mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp

I have 7 tables in my DB.
I want to get the 20 **latest** inserted data from the tables.
The tables are all build like this:

```
   id          Link         date           
========-----========----==============
integer       String      Timestamp
```

Comment: UNION ALL, order by, LIMIT 20. (But why 7 similar tabels?)

Comment: `ORDER BY date DESC`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from
(
Select date from table
union all
select date from table2
) as t
order by t.date desc
limit 20
```

Comment: isn't it `order by t.date desc` ?

Comment: yes! you use desc to start with the largest.

Comment: @JackJreigeChalouhy  thanks, this works fine :)

Comment: I added a few more parameters, so it should work faster:                        `select * from (                                                                                                 ( select date from table order by date desc limit 20 )                                    union all                                                                                                            ( select date from table2 order by date desc limit 20 )                                      ... )  as t order by t.date desc limit 20`